# CAST(unix_timestamp(Column,Format)) showing wrong date in Spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I need to change the date format in a spark dataframe which is in String. I need to remove / as well as 00:00:00. I tried to use

```
to_date(unix_timestamp($"Date", "YYYY-MM-DD 00-00-00").cast("timestamp"))
```

The format is changing as expected but with some random date. I found the issue is with `unix_timestamp`
  The dataframe is imported from CSV file. I got a solution using regex but it would be better to know why it is not working.

Code used: (The code may not be exact but similar)

```
df.select(unix_timestamp($"Date", "MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"),$"Date")
```

[Sample Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odPgZ.png)

Comment: Which version of Spark do you use?

Comment: The version is 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
df.select((unix_timestamp($"Date", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") * 1000).cast("timestamp"), $"Date")
```

See [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11724) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Works when I use yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. So what is the difference between Caps MM:DD vs mm:dd:yy?